# .Net Regular Expression(Regex)

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, variables, split

VB.NET separate strings using regex split? 
Im having a logical error with the pattern string variable, the error occur  after i extend the string from "(-)" to "(-)(+)(/)(*)"..

```
  Dim input As String = txtInput.Text
    Dim pattern As String = "(-)(+)(/)(*)"

    Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, pattern)
    For Each match As String In substrings
        lstOutput.Items.Add(match)
```

This is my output when my pattern string variable is "-" it works fine

```
input: dog-
output: dog 
        -
```

My desired output(This is want i want to happen) but there is something wrong with the code.. its having an error after i did this "(-)(+)(/)(*)" even this 
"(-)" + "(+)" + "(/)" + "(*)"

```
input: dog+cat/tree
output: dog
    +
    cat
    /
    tree
```

when space character input from textbox to listbox

```
input: dog+cat/ tree
output: dog
+
cat
/



tree
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *character class*, not the sequence  of subpatterns inside separate capturing gorups:

```
Dim pattern As String = "([+/*-])"
```

This pattern will match and *capture* into Group 1 (and thus, all the captured values will be part of the resulting array) a char that is either a `+`, `/`, `*` or `-`. Note the position of the hyphen: since it is the last char in the character class, it is treated as a literal `-`, not a range operator.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5B%2B%2F*-%5D%29&i=one%2Btwo-three%2Ffour-five):

[image]

Comment: Wiktor thanks it worked but what if a space character ? i did add a 1 space character inside of the bracket but the output makes the space too far as in 3 spaces...

Comment: Add a space at the beginning: `[ +/*-]` - the point is that `-` must be at the end.

Comment: the space character work but the space extend to 2 character space i think the problem must be on the listbox.. see my new edit output above..

Comment: If you want me to help, please provide a sample string and expected output. Please wrap the code in comments within `\``